# print Signed PDF Files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itext

```
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.Verb = "print";
            info.FileName = pdf2print;
            //info.CreateNoWindow = false;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            //info.UseShellExecute = true;

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = info;
            //MessageBox.Show("Print Will Start Now");
            p.Start();
```

But many times PC gets hanged or the files are not printed in the sequence they are submitted for print.

So is there any `itextsharp` function or procedure directly to print to a selected printer?

Comment: Check the document properties of the signed PDF file and see if Printing is "Allowed".

Comment: But even i never checked it , the documents get printed except that some times the printing simply stoped. I want to know any alternate method to do printing of such around 600-1000 documents  are printwd daily . But some day every thing stops